# React storing JSX.Element inside a variables performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Is there any differences terms of performance and rerendering in the following components?

```
const Component1 = () => {
  const someVar = "hi";

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>{someVar}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and this?

```
const Component2 = () => {
  const someVar = "hi";

  const myListEl = (
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>{someVar}</li>
    </ul>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      {myListEl}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I know that extracting jsx into variable might cause a small performance hit due to assigning it to a variable then reading it in "return" but other than that, is there any other factors?

Comment: There will be no measurable difference between those. The act of assigning to a variable is ridiculously fast, or maybe even 0 if the browser optimizes it away. And react's not going to do anything differently, because it doesn't even have a way to know you did this.

Comment: IMO there shouldn't be any difference between these 2 snippets but If you want to separate out JSX then why not just create different separate component instead of nested component. That way you can achieve clean and separate component.

Comment: @DecPK sometimes to make conditional rendering more easier to read if the JSX is kinda long. Yes, it could be done with separated component too but I would have to create the interface for all the props again. Since the component doesn't need any functionality of hooks and I only want to split the code, that's why I just store in variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many of the folks in comments mention. There is very little chance there will be a discernible difference in performance between either option. However, if for some reason this component was much expensive to render, using memoization could be a great option. `useMemo` or `useCallback` would work. I generally recommend `useMemo` but if you want to create a memoized component that takes an input such as "index" `useCallback` is a great alternative.

An example of an "expensive component" would be a component that uses `array.map(() => <SomeComponent>)` to create many components or includes a for loop that might re-render each time the page refreshes.

```
const ComponentMemo = useMemo(() => {
  const someVar = "hi";

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>{someVar}</li>
    </ul>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      {myListEl}
    </div>
  );
},[]) // add a state variable to this dependency array if you want this component to re-render and use the up-to-date state value each time this variable changes
```

You would use this as such

```
<div>
{ComponentMemo}
</div>
```

Or in the useCallback way

```
const componentCreateFunction = useCallback(() => {
  const someVar = "hi";

  const myListEl = (
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>{someVar}</li>
    </ul>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      {myListEl}
    </div>
  );
},[]); // This dependency array behaves a bit different, you update this dep array with state variables so that when you CALL the function again, it can use this updated state value within the useCallback closure.
```

You would use this as such

```
<div>
{componentCreateFunction()}
</div>
```